# Can these database calls be optimized?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project to further learn php and how it can be used to interface with a mysql database. The project is a forum, with the page in question displaying all the topics in a category. I'd like to know if I am handling my calls efficiently, and if not, how can I structure my queries so they are more efficient? I know its a small point with a website that isn't used outside of testing, but I'd like to get a handle on this early.

```
<?php
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$tid = $_GET['tid'];

// starting breadcrumb stuff
$catname = mysql_query("SELECT cat_name FROM categories WHERE id = '".$cid."'");
$rcatname = mysql_fetch_array( $catname );
$topicname = mysql_query("SELECT topic_title FROM topics WHERE id = '".$tid."'");
$rtopicname = mysql_fetch_array( $topicname );
echo "<p style='padding-left:15px;'><a href='/'> Home </a> &raquo; <a href='index.php'> Categories </a> &raquo; <a href='categories.php?cid=".$cid."'> ".$rcatname['cat_name']."</a> &raquo; <a href='#'> ".$rtopicname['topic_title']. "</a></p>";
//end breadcrumb

$sql = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE cat_id='".$cid."' AND id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Reply' onClick=\"window.location = 'reply.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'\" />";
    echo "<table>";
    if ($_SESSION['user_id']) { echo "<thead><tr><th>Author</th><th>Topic &raquo; ".$rtopicname['topic_title']."</th></thead><hr />"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply.</p><hr /></td></tr>"; 
    }
    echo "<tbody>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE cat_id='".$cid."' AND topic_id='".$tid."'";
        $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
            echo "<tr><td width='200' valign='top'>by ".$row2['post_creator']." <hr /> Posted on:<br />".$row2['post_date']."<hr /></td><td valign='top'>".$row2['post_content']."</td></tr>";
        }
        $old_views = $row['topic_views'];
        $new_views = $old_views + 1;
        $sql3 = "UPDATE topics SET topic_views='".$new_views."' WHERE cat_id='".$cid."' AND id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1";
        $res3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "</tbody></table>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
  }
?>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: This might be a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: **WARNING** your code is very susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Run a performance analysis and check the indices. While others have said, reducing round-trips can help performance (especially in situations with latency), so can correctly indexed queries. On a personal note, I would not touch this code until the queries are replaced with parameterized queries.

Comment: Thank you all the awesome input, there is a bunch of stuff here that I hadn't previously considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of extra things I would do when I write a code like above:

1. Never use `*` in `SELECT` statement when you know the columns you are going to use.
2. Always use `or die(mysql_error())` when executing the query.
3. Unset the result sets once the result sets has served its purpose.
4. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape the injections when using some substitutions in your queries.

Comment: 4. Always sanitize user input.

Comment: 4.1 I might suggest to simply use PDO if you can.

Comment: I can *not* support an answer that *does not recommend placeholders*. There are some things which are wrong 98% of the time. Dynamic SQL string building -- even with `mysql_real_escape_string` -- is one of them. (Also, these are good tips, but don't address the fundamentally flawed structure.)

Comment: Lots of great suggestions here, thanks a bunch. Looks like I have a lot of reading to do!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a classic `(n+1)` query mistake that could die a latent death.  You get a key using one round trip, then you loop over the results to get n values based on it.  If the first result set is large you'll have a lot of network round trips.

You could bring it all back in one go with a JOIN and save yourself a lot of network latency.

Comment: +1 For ... actually getting the to what may be the "real issue", or at least one of them. Might also be index related for all I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've got a lot of work ahead of me to wrap my head around all of the input I've received.

Comment: +1 returning the favor.  I noticed I had basically copied your answer after I saw it but I figured the last sentence of mine was worth leaving up since it's in laymens' terms so people like me can understand :)

Answer (score 3):

The statements themselves are fairly simple so there's not much you can do to optimize them further that I know of.  However, if you create some business objects and cache the data into them on a single call and then access data from the business objects then it could be faster.

In other words, 1 SQL call for 1,000 rows is going to be much faster than 1,000 calls for a single row.

Comment: The last sentence should be made more prominent. Also should consider the impact of indexes ... or lack of.

Comment: +1 from me.  That's what the (n+1) query mistake is all about.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll have to look into business objects.

Comment: @pst Feel free to make any edits you think will improve the answer.